# How can I prevent Bootstrap interfering with my WordPress theme and default CSS in a custom plugin?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, plugins, wordpress-theming

I'm creating a WordPress plugin and I need Bootstrap. I'm using the Bootstrap CDN.

To be more specific, I don't want to change code in the CSS
And my plugin is toggled by a shortcode so I can't just target a single page

```
wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-css','https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap-css');
```

But the problem is it interfere with my wordpress css (theme , title etc..)
Someone know how to resolve that ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change the CSS. You can't expect your plugin users to load Bootstrap into any random theme or they'll face the exact problems you are. Also, Bootstrap is a bit heavy for a plugin. You probably want a vastly reduced version of it anyway.

1. Prefix all Bootstrap classes in your stylesheet and markup with a code for your plugin. Select a prefix that's likely to be unique, like `ws_`.
2. Reduce the library to just what you actually need and minify it. Include it as a file with your plugin package.
3. Don't be heavy-handed with Bootstrap styling unless you're marketing your plugin as Bootstrap-only. Use layout and spacing classes, but maybe not button or color classes, for example, unless the user opts in to Bootstrap styling.

Comment: Thx , i'll see what i can do

Comment: You're welcome, but please take the [tour] to learn how to use this site. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.